# Different XML results using XML auto in SQL Server 2000 and 2008

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, t-sql

How to generate the same xml output for SQL Server 2000 (compatibility level=80) and SQL Server 2008 (compatibility level=100) ?

Example :

```sql
create table #temp(a int, b varchar(10))

insert into #temp
select 1, 'abc'
union
select 1,'def'

select * 
from
    (select * from #temp child) parent 
for xml auto, elements
```

Output for SQL Server 2000 (compatibility level 80):

```
<child>
        <a>1</a>
        <b>abc</b>
</child>
<child>
         <a>1</a>
         <b>def</b>
</child>
```

Output for SQL Server 2008 (compatibility level 100):

```
  <parent>
           <a>1</a>
           <b>abc</b>
  </parent>
  <parent>
           <a>1</a>
           <b>def</b>
  </parent>
```

Thanks

Comment: Off topic: If ever possible go for an upgrade. 2000 isn't even supported any more (quite a while). The advantages and new features are - in most cases - worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the alias `child` with `parent` should do the trick:

```sql
create table #temp(a int, b varchar(10))

insert into #temp
select 1, 'abc'
union
select 1,'def'

select * 
from
    (select * from #temp parent) parent 
for xml auto, elements
```

I tried this query with compatibility level 80 and 100. In both cases the result is:

```xml
<parent>
  <a>1</a>
  <b>abc</b>
</parent>
<parent>
  <a>1</a>
  <b>def</b>
</parent>
```